# How can I make a spiral galaxy type object

Tags: objects

I have tried all sorts of tutorials and nothing works right.  I need a relatively simple way to make 4 curving arms like a spiral galaxy.  I can't think of a better way to describe what I am looking for.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I have tried this solution to no effect at all.  When I go to do the rotation in proportional editing it only affects the area around the center.  Nothing I do increases the range of influence.  Mouse wheel just zooms the screen and Page up and down have no effect at all.  I am using Blender 3.0.  Did they change the functionality.  I read and reread the section in the manual and those are the only instructions.  All I want to do is to make a galaxy like swiral.  It can't be this annoyingly hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

model this shape:

[image]

Select the center, enable the *Proportional Editing*, make a rotation on Z, correct the result in the *Operator Box* if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb.  How do you model that shape.  I have tried a dozen things and none look like that or have that behavior when I rotate the center of whatever I made.

Comment: I finally pulled it off.  Thank so much.

Comment: hello, sorry I've just seen your first comment, but nice if you succeeded!